# How to display coordinates from class?

Tags: c++, class, object

I am having issues displaying coordinates that are read into a class. This is my first time using classes so please be understanding!
Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Vector{
private:
float x;
float y;
public:
Vector(float f1, float f2)
{
    x=f1;
    y=f2;   
}

Vector(){}

float display()
{
    Vector v;
    cout << "(" << v.x << "," << v.y << ")" << endl;
    return 0;
}


};

 int main()
{
  Vector v1(0.5, 0.5); 

   cout << "v1 ";
   v1.display();
   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

It prints

```
v1 (-1.07374e+008,-1.07374e+008)
```

Comment: In display, you create an object v then you display v's coordinates. Remove v.

Comment: You can also overload `operator<<` of `std::ostream`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981836/how-can-i-use-cout-myclass

Comment: @NO_NAME This is the first time OP is using class and you asking him to overload a operator lol

Comment: @AngelusMortis Why not? Is worth knowing about this possibility. 
For now, he does not have to understand this. He just need to copy the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not printing out the coordinates of the Vector you created in `main()` but a default created one in your function. Instead of

```
float display()
{
    Vector v;
    cout << "(" << v.x << "," << v.y << ")" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

You need

```
float display()
{
    //Vector v; remove this
    cout << "(" << x << "," << y << ")" << endl;
    //           no v.x       no v.y
    return 0;
}
```

I suggest you change the default constructor to

```
Vector() : x(0), y(0) {}
```

So it would have printed

```
v1 (0,0)
```

You should also change

```
Vector(float f1, float f2)
{
    x=f1;
    y=f2;   
}
```

To

```
Vector(float f1, float f2) : x(f1), y(f2) {}
```

As it is a good habit to get into.  This can save resources and CPU cycles when dealing with non POD types.  For more information see [Why should I prefer to use member initialization list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926752/why-should-i-prefer-to-use-member-initialization-list)

Answer (score 1):

the `Vector v;` line is a mistake. You are basically creating a new uninitialized vector instead of crating your own instance.

one correction would be:

```
int display()
{
    cout << "(" << x << "," << y << ")" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

since x and y are member of this class

Comment: Thank you, this really helps and is working now. I have another issue with it though. I want to initialise a coordinate set to (0,0) if its undeclared. For example, if I add: Vector v2(); v2.display();      it doesn't currently output (0,0), instead something similar to the exponential value in OP.

Comment: @Surge: two simple choice for it: use default value (not recommended) or create a new constructor with no input parameters `Vector(){x=0.0; y=0.0;}`