# How To change array structure to vector?

Tags: c++11

the goal in the driver program is to Change the data structure that stores the membershipTypes from an array to a vector.

and to also declare an iterator i to index this array.

what i did so far i think is correct but when i try to cout the information i get no operator << matches this operand how do i fix my code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "personType.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector <membershipType> members; // vector of membershipTypes
    vector <membershipType>::iterator i; // iterator for the members vector
    string x, i1, i2;
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("infile.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        myfile >> members[i].lastName >> members[i].firstName >> members[i].personNum >>
            members[i].personID >> members[i].address.streetAddressNum >>
            members[i].address.streetName >> members[i].address.streetType >> members[i].address.city >> members[i].address.stateInitials >> members[i].address.zipCode >> members[i].gender;
        myfile >> i1 >> i2;
        myfile >> members[i].membership_status;
        myfile >> members[i].membership_type;
        members[i].setInterest1(i1);
        members[i].setInterest2(i2);
        members[i].print_membership_type();
    }
    myfile.close();
    system("pause");

    return 0;

    for (vector<membershipType>::iterator i = members.begin(); i != members.end(); ++i) 
    { cout << *i << endl; }
}
```

Comment: Note: You should loop as `for(auto const &theMember: members){}` since you are using C++11.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use cout << myclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981836/how-can-i-use-cout-myclass)

Comment: what do you mean?