# How does cin and cout support different data types?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, cin, cout

I know `std::cin >> x` will store vales from the input stream in the variable `x`. I also know that `cin` will scan the input stream as long as possible to get a valid representation of `x` (skipping any white space). However, how is this behavior defined for different data types, and what data types are supported?

Does `cin` simply have a different overload on `>>` for each type? Does it only support fundamental data types?

Similarly, how does `std::cout` know how to print out a value? I'm assuming it uses an implicit conversion to a string, but I couldn't confirm that.

Comment: You are asking several questions. The 3rd part is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981836/how-can-i-use-cout-myclass

Comment: Thanks. I was assuming they were related, and that answering one would help with the others.

Comment: `operator>>` for input and `operator<<` for output are overloaded for each type. It doesn't only support fundamental types, e.g. std::string isn't fundamental, and you can overload it yourself to support your own classes. `cout` doesn't know how to print out a value, the relevant overload for the type you're passing does though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler collects a set of functions named `operator<<` (or `operator>>`) from a variety of places:

- current scope
- members of the left-hand operand and its base classes
- namespace of the left-hand operand (which may be defined inside the class using the `friend` keyword)
- namespace of the right-hand operand (which may be defined inside the class using the `friend` keyword)
- built-in versions that apply to primitive integral types

It then performs overload resolution in the same way as when calling a function with an "ordinary" name in order to determine which of these to use.  Implicit conversions are considered during overload resolution, but generally providing iostream support for a data type includes providing a match that is more direct than an implicit conversion to string would be (for example, reference conversions are better).

Since the left-hand operand here is `std::cout` (or `std::cin`), you don't have much control over its members or its namespace.  And you cannot change the built-in versions.  But that still gives you several ways to add support for new types -- as the program author, use the current scope, and as a library author, use the namespace of the class you write.

Comment: Thank you. With this clarification, I was able to research further. I found this post to be quite helpful: [Overloading stream insertion (<>) operators in C++](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overloading-stream-insertion-operators-c/)