# How to implement derivable C++ class string representation including class name

Tags: c++

I come from the python world where `__str__` and `__repr__` have been very useful to my development and execution workflow output.
I would like to implement such things in C++.
[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981836/how-can-i-use-cout-myclass) has been useful, however I would like that the string output includes the class name and that it be easily overloadable by subclasses.
Here is a code example:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

class Parent
{
    static constexpr const char* clsName = "Parent";
    std::string _label;
public:
    Parent(std::string& label) : _label(label) {}

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, 
                                    Parent const &ref)
    {   
        os << clsName << "(";
        ref.print(os); 
        os << ")";
        return os; 
    }
    void print(std::ostream &os) const
    { os << _label; }
};

class Child : public Parent
{
    static constexpr const char* clsName = "Child";
public:
    Child(std::string& label) : Parent(label) {}
};
```

My intent here is that the `Child::operator<<` use it own `clsName` static private data, without having to overload the whole operator for each subclass.
Unfortunately this strategy does not work:

```
int main()
{
    std::string l("some label");
    Child x(l);
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

Will output

```
Parent(some label)
```

(I would like to see `Child(some label)`).

Comment: Meh, it's a bit more complex than my answer suggests because of the way you've organised your functions. Don't have time to expand it.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a `virtual` member function to get the class name.

I would also make `print` a `virtual` member function to allow derived classes to enhance what's being done in the base class.

I suggest a couple more enhancements:

1. Make the argument to the constructors a `const&`.
2. The `operator<<` function does not need to be a `friend`.

Here's an updated version of your classes.

```
class Parent
{
   private:
      static constexpr const char* clsName = "Parent";
      std::string _label;

   public:
      Parent(std::string const& label) : _label(label) {}

      virtual std::string getClassName() const
      {
         return clsName;
      }

      virtual void print(std::ostream &os) const
      {
         os << _label;
      }
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, Parent const &ref)
{   
   os << ref.getClassName() << "(";
   ref.print(os); 
   os << ")";
   return os; 
}

class Child : public Parent
{
   private:
      static constexpr const char* clsName = "Child";

   public:
      virtual std::string getClassName() const
      {
         return clsName;
      }

      virtual void print(std::ostream &os) const
      {
         // Nothing to do for this class in particual.
         // Just use the Parent implementation.
         Parent::print(os);
      }

      Child(std::string const& label) : Parent(label) {}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make `clsName` a virtual function. Currently `Child::clsName` merely hides `Parent::clsName`, you can still access `Parent::clsName` from within `Child`.

You also should declare the destructor of `Parent` to be virtual, which means that the other special members also should be declared. All five can be implemented as `= default`.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

class Parent
{
    virtual std::string clsName() const { return "Parent" };
    std::string _label;
public:
    Parent(const std::string& label) : _label(label) {}
    virtual ~Parent() = default;
    Parent(const Parent &) = default;
    Parent(Parent &&) = default;
    Parent& operator=(const Parent &) = default;
    Parent& operator=(Parent &&) = default;

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, Parent const &ref)
    {   
        return os << ref.clsName() << "(" << ref._label << ")";
    }
};

class Child : public Parent
{
    std::string clsName() const override { return "Child" };
public:
    using Parent::Parent;
};
```