# How to pass a custom class to std::cout?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I am trying to write a C++ Program, but am greatly struggling with the copy assignment section. Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CarCounter {
   public:
      CarCounter();
      CarCounter& operator=(const CarCounter& objToCopy);
      void SetCarCount(const int setVal) {
         carCount = setVal;
      }
      int GetCarCount() const {
         return carCount;
      }
   private:
      int carCount;
};

CarCounter::CarCounter() {
   carCount = 0;
}

// FIXME write copy assignment operator

/* Your solution goes here  */
CarCounter& CarCounter::operator=(const CarCounter& objToCopy) {
   CarCounter nobj;
   cout << objToCopy.carCount << endl;
   nobj.carCount =  objToCopy.carCount;
   cout << nobj.carCount << endl;
   cout << *this << endl;
   return *this;
}

int main() {
   CarCounter frontParkingLot;
   CarCounter backParkingLot;

   frontParkingLot.SetCarCount(12);
   backParkingLot = frontParkingLot;

   cout << "Cars counted: " << backParkingLot.GetCarCount();

   return 0;
}
```

And the output is:

> main.cpp: In member function ‘CarCounter& CarCounter::operator=(const
>   CarCounter&)’: main.cpp:30:9: error: no match for ‘operator<<’
>   (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream}’ and
>   ‘CarCounter’)
>       cout << *this << endl;

I know it's probably an obvious rookie mistake, but I'm new to C++. I appreciate all the help I can get. Thanks!

Comment: What do you expect `cout << *this` to do? Why do you have output statements in an assignment operator in the first place?

Comment: He's most likely using those for debugging purposes... I think.

Comment: Semi-related: `CarCounter` meets the requirements for [the Rule of Zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). There is no need for an assignment operator. You can leave it out or declare it in the class as `CarCounter& operator=(const CarCounter& objToCopy) = default;` to make it clear that the class uses the default assignment logic.

Comment: How is the compiler supposed to know how to print a `CarCounter`? If you want to be able directly use the `<<` operator with a `CarCounter`, you're going to need to tell the compiler how you want the object to be printed by overloading the operator for your class.

Comment: Please give your question a more descriptive title. Almost all questions are about how to fix an issue, so that's useless.

Comment: Sorry about the nondescript title; didn't quite know what to name it. Yes, I was trying to use cout for debugging (working on an assignment in a lousy web-ide and can't debug).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use cout << myclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981836/how-can-i-use-cout-myclass)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your copy assignment operator should look like this:

```
CarCounter& CarCounter::operator=(const CarCounter& objToCopy) {
   carCount = objToCopy.carCount;
   return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass your custom class to `cout`. The error is basically saying that your class `CarCounter` is incompatible to be piped to `cout`. It seems like that line is completely unneeded and can be removed.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I marked the other one as the answer, but this actually explained why.