# Operator error and edge insertion problem in an unweighted, undirected graph

Tags: c++, class, output, graph-theory

I've got several problems with my adjacency graph in C++. I fixed some of the main errors, but still can run and test the program. I'm not sure if the `newEdge()` method is working properly, if the vector in the vector is right created, and most importantly how to display the edges in the graph.

There is the code and I marked the lines with errors with "!":

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream> 
#include <vector>


using namespace std;


struct Edge
{
    int begin;
    int end;
};

class Graph
{
private:

    int numOfNodes;
    vector<vector<Edge>> baseVec;

public:

    Graph(int numOfNodes)
    {   
        baseVec.resize(baseVec.size() + numOfNodes);
    }

    void newEdge(Edge edge)
    {
        if (edge.begin >= numOfNodes-1 || edge.end >= numOfNodes-1 || edge.begin < 0 || edge.end < 0)
        {
            cout << "Invalid edge!\n";
        }
        baseVec[edge.begin].emplace_back(edge.end); !!
        baseVec[edge.end].emplace_back(edge.begin); !!
    }
    void display()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < baseVec.size(); i++)
        {
            cout << "\n Adjacency list of vertex " << i << "\n head "; !!!
            for (int j = 0; j < baseVec[i].size(); j++)  !!!
            {
                cout << baseVec[i][j] << " "; !!!!!!!
                cout << endl;
            }
        }
    }

};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, Edge const &m)
{
    return os << m.begin << m.end;
}

int main()
{
    int vertex, numberOfEdges, begin, end;
    cout << "Enter number of nodes: ";
    cin >> vertex;
    numberOfEdges = vertex * (vertex - 1);

    Edge edge;
    Graph g1(vertex);
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfEdges; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter edge ex.1 2 (-1 -1 to exit): \n";
        cin >> edge.begin >> edge.end;
        if ((begin == -1) && (end == -1))
        {
            break;
        }
        g1.newEdge(edge);
    }
    g1.display();
    return 0;
}
```

I overloaded the << operator, not sure if it's right and the two errors I have in Visual Studio are:

> '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
>
> binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type '_Ty' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

This is a new version [of my prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53326934/display-and-add-methods-for-adjacency-list-graph).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assumming your `Graph` is a model over an undirected graph with a fixed number of nodes, based your program logic.

Your program has quite a few problems.

**First**, in member function `Graph::newEdge`, the precondition is wrong,

```
edge.source >= numOfNodes - 1 || edge.target >= numOfNodes - 1
```

It should be,

```
edge.source >= numOfNodes || edge.target >= numOfNodes
```

More importantly, if the precondition fails, `newEdge` function should return immediately, instead of adding the edge.

**Second problem** is with constructor `Graph::Graph`. 1) private member variable `numOfNodes` is not initialized. 2) There is no need to call `baseVec.resize()`. A vector of a given size can be created directly. 3) Member initializer list should be preferred.

```
Graph(int numOfNodes) : numOfNodes(numOfNodes), baseVec(num0fNodes) {}
```

**Third problem** is with member variable `Graph::baseVec`.

```
vector<vector<Edge>> baseVec;
```

Suppose your have a graph of 4 nodes, with edges inserted with the following sequence, (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 2), (2, 3). The process should be,

step 1: (0, 1)

```
0: 1
1: 0
```

step 2: (0, 2)

```
0: 1 2
1: 0
2: 0
```

step 3: (0, 3)

```
0: 1 2 3
1: 0
2: 0
3: 0
```

step 4: (1, 2)

```
0: 1 2 3
1: 0 2
2: 0 1
3: 0
```

step 5: (2, 3)

```
0: 1 2 3
1: 0 2
2: 0 1 3
3: 0 2
```

What is stored into baseVec is not of type `Edge`, but `int`. The source is the row index and the target is column index. With that, the output operator for `struct Edge` isn't necessary.

**At last**, in `main` function, the assignment on `numOfEdges` isn't necessary. I guess your logic is the maximum number of edges on the graph is `vertex * (vertex - 1)`, but `newEdge` member function does not check for duplicate edges. You have to modify the member function to make it useful.

See the full demo on [wandbox.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2hguI0Ae8xB2dryd)