# Print Class-type Properties ( cout << class.property )

Tags: c++

I'm learning C++, and I have a question about print class type property.

I'm trying to get `Point(x, y)`'s position, and print it.

Getting position is perfectly work as I thought, but printing does not.

I think it should work, but it doesn't, maybe I am missing something.

Should I cast it to any other value type which could print out?

so I just tried `cout << "The position is: " << p1.getPosition();` and I got an error:

```
prog.cc:29:7: error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream' {aka 'std::basic_ostream'} and 'Point')
   29 |  cout << p1.getPosition();
      |  ~~~~ ^~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |  |                     |
      |  |                     Point
      |  std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream}
```

Here's my code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Point{
    double x;
    double y;
public:
    Point getPosition();
    void setPosition(double x_, double y_);
    Point operator+(const Point& p);
    Point(double x_, double y_)
    {
        x = x_;
        y = y_;
    }
};

Point Point::getPosition(){ return Point(x, y); }
void Point::setPosition(double x, double y){    x = this->x;    y = this->y;    }
Point Point::operator+(const Point& p)
{
    return Point((x+p.x), (y+p.y));
}


int main(void)
{
    Point p1(5.0, 5.0);
    cout << "The position is: " << p1.getPosition() << endl;       //error occured
    return 0;   
}
```

Thanks you for your help :)

Comment: You need to create a custom ostream operator for your class, like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981836/how-can-i-use-cout-myclass

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use cout << myclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981836/how-can-i-use-cout-myclass)

Comment: @NutCracker Almost the answer :)