# How can I override the << operator for a class without it being in its namespace?

Tags: c++

I have a custom class that I am trying to print, I have it working how I am unsure why it is working and I was hoping someone could explain it. Taking the idea from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981836/how-can-i-use-cout-myclass) I have created a small example,

```
class myclass { 

public:
    int i = 5;
};
```

and manages to print it by using,

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, myclass const &m) { 
    return os << m.i;
}

myclass x;
std::cout << x;
```

However, other override operators have to include the class namespace such as,

```
myclass myclass::operator+(const myclass & c) {
    
    string temp;
    temp.i = i + c.i;
    return temp;
}
```

Notice here how I needed the namespace for the class `myclass::operator+`?
Why was this not required to work for the `<<` operator? How is it associated with `myclass`?

i.e I expected something like this,

```
                 v----this added
std::ostream myclass::operator<<(std::ostream &os, myclass const &m) { 
    return os << m.i;
}
```

Comment: That's not a namespace. That's just the class name. A typename is not a namespace.

Comment: `However, other override operators have to include the class namespace such as,` No they don't, they can be implemented as free functions as well. I.e. `myclass operator+(const myclass & a, const myclass & b)`

Comment: Are you declaring the operator inside your class definition (in your `.h` header file) or only in your `.cpp` file?

Comment: Unrelated: `myclass::operator+` is weird looking. Allocates a `string`, operates on it, and then returns it, when it looks like the function should be returning a `myclass`.

Comment: Useful search term: ["Free function".](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861914/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-term-free-function-in-c)

Comment: Most `operator` overloads can be implemented as class methods, where `this` is handled as the left-hand operand. But `operator<<` and `operator>>` overloads can't be when dealing with `std::ostream`/`std::istream` I/O, as that would require those overloads to be added to the `std::ostream`/`std:istream` classes themselves, which is not allowed. Hence why custom `operator<<`/`operator>>` overloads in this situation are always implemented as non-member functions that take a `std::ostream`/`std::istream` as the 1st parameter.