# Vector and smart_pointer. I don't get the actual numbers

Tags: c++, vector, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class Test {
private:
    int data;
public:
    Test() : data{} { std::cout << "\tctor Test(" << data << ")\n"; }
    Test(int data) : data{ data } {
        std::cout << "\tctor Test(" << data << ")\n";
    }
    int get_data() const { return data; }
    ~Test() { std::cout << "\tdtor Test(" << data << ")\n"; }
};


std::unique_ptr<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Test>>> make() {

    std::unique_ptr<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Test>>> ptr = std::make_unique<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Test>>>();

    return ptr;
}

void fill(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Test>>& vec, int num) {

    for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {

        std::cout << "Number " << i << ": " <<std::endl;
        int a;
        std::cin >> a;

        std::shared_ptr<Test> ptr(new Test(a));
        vec.push_back(std::move(ptr));
    }
}

void display(const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Test>>& vec) {

    
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        
        std::cout << vec[i] << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Test>>> vec_ptr;
    vec_ptr = make();
    std::cout << "How many data points: ";
    int num;
    std::cin >> num;
    fill(*vec_ptr, num);
    display(*vec_ptr);
    return 0;

}
```

I want to print out my vector with the display function, but I only get the adress. I only got something like this:

```
How many data points: 3
 Number 1:
 1
         ctor Test(1)
 Number 2:
 2
         ctor Test(2)
 Number 3:
 3
         ctor Test(3)
 014A5820
 014A5850
 014A9460
         dtor Test(1)
         dtor Test(2)
         dtor Test(3)
```

How do i get the actual numbers? Can someone please tell me what I do wrong.

Comment: Try `std::cout << *vec[i] << std::endl;` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Test` class has the `get_data()` function to get the number, so use that.

Changing the line

```
std::cout << vec[i] << std::endl;
```

to

```
std::cout << vec[i] << " : " << vec[i]->get_data() << std::endl;
```

will give you something like this:

```
0x18f4190 : 1
0x18f41f0 : 2
0x18f41d0 : 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Your vector contains pointers.  Whether they're `shared_ptr`, `unique_ptr`, or plain dumb C-style pointers makes no difference.  To get the value at the pointer you need the `*` operator to dereference the pointer.

```
std::cout << *vec[i] << std::endl;
```

In this case you haven't defined an `operator<<` for the class the pointer points at, so that won't work.  But you can do [as MikeCAT suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68084833/5987) and *call* a function on the pointer.

```
std::cout << vec[i]->get_data() << std::endl;
```

Comment: This will lead to compilation error because how to print `Test` via `ostream` is not defined. How to define: [c++ - How can I use cout << myclass - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981836/how-can-i-use-cout-myclass)

Comment: @MikeCAT yes I realized that and was correcting just as you made your comment.  Thanks for the additional link.