# How to iterate through a returned custom class and print it's members

Tags: c++, return, return-value

I don't know how to print a returned value of a custom object.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Person{
private:
    string name;
    int age; 
public:
    Person(){
    };

    Person(string name, int age){
       this->name = name; 
       this->age = age; 
    }

    string getName(){
        return name; 
    }
};

class listOfPeople{
private:
    vector <Person> myList;
public:
    void fillTheList(Person p){
        myList.push_back(p);
    }

    Person findPerson(string name){
        for(Person p : myList){
            if(p.getName() == name) {
                return p; // returns a person
            }
        }
        return {};
    }
};

int main(){
   Person p1("Vitalik Buterin", 30); 
   Person p2("Elon musk", 50); 
   listOfPeople L; 
   L.fillTheList(p1); 
   L.fillTheList(p2); 
   Person p = L.findPerson("Vitalik"); //  I don't know what to do here (I want to print Vitalik's information, the full name and age)
   return 0; 
}
```

I don't know how to print the informations of the returned value. I tried different things but can't get the right logic.

Comment: Sorry to hear that you "don't know how to print the informations of the returned value", but your question is not clear. What does "print a returned value of a custom object" mean?

Comment: `name_of_person_object.name_of_member_to_access`

Comment: @SamVarshavchik the function findPerson returns a person if he's found in the list. That person has name and age. I store the person in a variable in the main method and now I want to print the name and age of that person

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981836/how-can-i-use-cout-myclass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Boost.PFR](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_pfr.html) a.k.a. "magic get" could be one option if you are willing to turn `Person` into an aggregate:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "boost/pfr.hpp"

struct Person {
    std::string name;
    int age;
};

int main() {
    Person p{"Foo Bar", 85};

    std::cout << boost::pfr::io(p) << '\n';
}
```

Output

```
{"Foo Bar", 85}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/M5MGxvjY4)

Comment: ohhh waaw that's exactly what I was looking for thank you Ted

Comment: @ThisIsMe You're welcome! This part of the library is "magic". I have very little idea how it works internally. :-)

Comment: unfortunately I got an error when trying to include it ('boost/pfr.hpp' file not found) it's a c++14 library and it seems I have another version 

Comment: @ThisIsMe It requires the boost library to be installed. It's available for all major platforms using the normal package installation procedures.

Comment: ahaa okey I'll install then  thanks again

Answer (score 1):

you just need

```
 std::cout << p.name << " is " << p.age <<'/n';
```

Comment: is this the only way to do it? what if I have a person with say 20 personal information like name, last name, age, job, salary ect... do I have to print them all like that? is there a way to automatically print the person's info?

Comment: @ThisIsMe there is no automatic way

Comment: In C++ there is no built-in reflection mechanism for the object to inspect itself and determine what its members are let alone know how to print them all.

Comment: @user4581301 oh yeah I see

Answer (score 0):

You can add a toString() function in the person class that returns a string with the object properties and then print it using:

```
// inside person
std::string toString() {
return this->name + " age: " + std::to_string(this->age);
}
```

```
std::cout << p.toString();
```

By adding this function to your class, every time you need to print the properties of person, just call `toString()`.

You could also add implementation to the operator `<<`, you can search how.

Comment: This should be call `toString`, as that is what the function actually does.